# Angular ng-model & filter using nested data vs top layer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of data displayed on my page that is broken down into `divs`. Each div represents an array of data in my object, pretty common.

I am trying to add a text box to my page where I can filter out the data and it will narrow down the results shown on the page as more data is entered into the text box.

For that, I added a filter on my `ngFor` like so: `*ngFor="let x of data | filter: filterString"`.

My text-box then uses `ngModel` to filter that data down:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter..." name="ruleFilter" id="ruleFilter" [(ngModel)]="filterString" (keyup)="onFilter($event)">
```

The issue I am having is that the filter seems to only be working with the top layer of data in my object. For example, the data below is what one of the results looks like in my `ngFor` loop. I can search `Omaha` just fine since its in the top level and it filters it down correctly.

However, If I look for something like `Campus` which is nested inside `Attribute`, it doesn't find it in the filter and no results are shown.

```
{
  "RuleParentID": "618",
  "RuleVersionID": "18",
  "MappedValue": "1",
  "ProcessingOrder": 1,
  "KeyID": "1",
  "Value": "Omaha",
  "IsRuleRetired": "0",
  "UserImpactCount": "0",
  "Attribute": [
    {
      "AttributeID": "6",
      "AttributeName": "Campus",
      "Operator": {
        "OperatorID": "3",
        "OperatorName": "In List",
        "SqlOperator": "IN"
      },
      "AttributeValue": [
        {
          "AttrValue": "1",
          "Value": "Omaha",
          "IsValueRetired": "0",
          "disabled": "False"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "AttributeID": "14",
      "AttributeName": "Grade",
      "Operator": {
        "OperatorID": "1",
        "OperatorName": "Greater Than",
        "SqlOperator": ">"
      },
      "AttributeValue": [
        {
          "AttrValue": "14",
          "Value": "14",
          "IsValueRetired": "0",
          "disabled": "False"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to have the model look at all layers of the object for my binding instead of just the top layer (which I only assume its doing at this time) ?

Update: Here is a plunker of what my basic setup is like: https://plnkr.co/edit/eywuWmPRseUkmVPbTEOf?p=preview

You will see the data model that searches by the top level properties just fine, but when I search for something nested, I don't get any results back.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the question, I think that to flat the data will help you:

```
var flattenObject = function(ob) {
    var toReturn = {};

    for (var i in ob) {
        if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
            var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
            for (var x in flatObject) {
                if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;

                toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
            }
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
};

let newData = flattenObject(data);
```

Code source: https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197

Comment: I could see how a flat object may solve this but I am not sure how to incorporate it into my `ngFor` loop. The object that I am looping over needs to remain the same but I need the filter to some how handle it differently.

Comment: If you have the flattenObject function in your .ts, you could do `*ngFor="let x of flattenObject(data)`

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood - I'm afraid I can't flatten the object at this point, its structure is heavily used throughout the remaining code. I was hoping that I could just adjust the filter to look through a flattened structure without actually changing the data.

Comment: in this case I wrote you are not keeping this changes, these are only applied for the loop :)

Comment: I get that but the 10 other components that this data is being received by is depending on its current structure to handle its iterations and displaying of values. I am unable to change all of the other code that is depending on the structure of this data.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use below option

1.In your component below variable

```
jsonVal:any=JSON; // for using JSON.stringify and indexOf
```

2. Use ***ngIf** to filter value from input with indexOf

```html
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterString">
    <div *ngFor="let data of result">
      <div *ngIf="jsonVal.stringify(data).indexOf(filterString)!= -1">{{data| json}}</div>
      </div>
```

code sample for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ht2afv?file=app/app.component.html

Just for testing , I have added another Object with Campus2 and Omaha2

Answer (score 0):

When filtering on a nested property of data you can use the `map` function or similar.

This will be in your component and not the template. Filtering using pipes in the template is [discouraged](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) by the Angular team for performance reasons.

Instead I would do something like this:

```
const data = [{//your data}]

let filteredData = [];

data.map(val => {
          if (val.Attribute.filter(name => name.AttributeName === "Foo").length > 0) {
            filteredData.push(val)
          }
        });
```

I am assuming your data is an array of objects.

Beware I am mutating my data object. To avoid this you do this:

```
const data = [{//your original data}]
const dataToFilter = JSON.Parse(JSON.stringify(data))
```

This will make copy of your data without references to your original object. Useful if you want to clear your filter. Not useful if your data object contains functions.

On re-reading your question I think this is not the solution you were looking for but rather a method to look anywhere in the data. For this you should probably flatten your data as suggested by Zelda7. Another approach would be to extend a filtering method to explicitly filter on all relevant fields.